# Rigorous energy estimate for advection-diffusion equation

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, parabolic-pde, hyperbolic-pde

Let $a \in L^q([0,T];L^p(\mathbb R^N))$ with $2/q + N/p \le 1$ and

- $q \in [2,\infty), p \in (N,\infty) \text{ if } N \ge 2$
- $q \in [2,4], p \in [2,\infty] \text{ if } N = 1$

and consider the advection-diffusion equation
$$
u_t -\Delta u + \mathrm{div} (au) = 0.
$$

Formally, multplying the equation by $u$ and integrating by parts, we get
$$
\frac{1}{2}\frac{d}{dt} \int_{\mathbb R^N} |u|^2 dx + \int_{\mathbb R^N} |\nabla u|^2 dx \le \int_{\mathbb R^N} |au| |\nabla u| dx
$$

Questions:

1. Can this energy estimate be made rigorous under the above assumptions? In particular, does the solution $u$ have enough regularity and decay at infinity to allow for the integration by parts?
2. Can you point out a reference with the optimal existence, uniqueness, and regularity result under the above assumptions?

Comment: @Medo The regularity of $u$ is part of the question (point (2)).

Comment: Usually one REQUIRES a minimum amount of regularity for the solution, in particular the very notion of solution one wishes to use depends on how much regularity one is ready to IMPOSE a priori (though a posteriori all solutions should be smoother than initially requested, by usual smoothing properties of the heat equation essentially). To be more realistic: we cannot really give a precise answer to your question unless you specify very carefully what you mean by "solution" (weak solution? energy solution? very weak solution? distributional solution? viscosity solutions? etc...)